# Add E-Mail header in django

Tags: django

So I have a code like this in the views.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
  send_mail(
  'subject',
  'message.',
  'info@xyz1234.de',
  ['test1234@gmail.com'],
  fail_silently=False,
#  headers={'List-Unsubscribe': '<http://www.xyz1234.de/unsubscribe123'},
)
```

I want to add the header 'List-Unsubscribe' but it doesn't work and I get a server error. If I use the code with '#' the code works fine. How can I add this header? Thanks.

Comment: There is no parameter named headers in send_mail code in django. What exactly you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can try to use [EmailMessage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage)

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage


email = EmailMessage(
    'subject',
    'message.',
    'info@xyz1234.de',
    to=['MYTEST@yandex.ru'],
    headers={'MY-UNIQUE-HEAD':  '<http://www.xyz1234.de/unsubscribe123'},
)

email.send(fail_silently=False)
```

settings

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'YOURUSER@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'YOURPASS'
```

[image]

Comment: looks good. I tried this now and at least I don't get an error but I don't receive the email that is being sent (unlike with the code in the initial posting).

Comment: i do test on my local, add example to the answer, check your email settings, please